# Polymer data binding to MySQL table data with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, data-binding, polymer

I am trying to sync some polymer element properties with a MySQL database on localhost using MAMP.

How do I pass the SQL data from a PHP variable to a Polymer data binded property?

The Polymer element is as follows:

```
<iron-ajax id="ajax"
  auto
  url="../src/data/php/get_data.php"
  last-response="{{lastResponse}}"
  handle-as="text"></iron-ajax>
```

...

```
static get properties() { return {

  lastResponse: {
    type: Object,
    value: {}
  }

}}

lastResponse () {
  console.log(this.lastResponse);
}
```

The PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "myDB";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests");
  $stmt->execute();

  // set the resulting array to associative
  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
      echo $v;
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP function

> get_data.php

should echo(not return) JSON, as:

```
$res['data'] = 'Hello!';
echo json_encode($res);
```

and iron-ajax should be set to receive JSON:

```
handle-as="json"
```

as in docs here

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax

In Polymer first execute the AJAX request, and then receive the data as this:

```
get_data_responseHandler: function(e) {
   console.log(e.detail.response);
}
```

That is how API point is created.